# where am I supposed to use the OAuth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, authentication, canvas, web

on the [facebook developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) it recommends using the OAuth Dialog where you use

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE`

replacing the the `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE` with what you have

my question is where am I supposed to put this?

do I put this somewhere on my index.php for my canvas page?

or aside from creating your app, do I need to make a website where info of my app should be displayed together with a link to my app using the OAuth Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create website that will have the content of the app, since facebook will display it in the iframe.

As for the link you mentioned, it is used to get permissions (basic information, user's email etc). If you need that kind of information about the user, you have to redirect him there so he can grant the permission. If your app doesn't require any information about the user, you can just skip the authorization part.